# Could not load file or assembly DotNetOpenAuth.Core

Tags: asp.net

Visual Studio 2017 is giving me a runtime error: 'Could not load file or assembly DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'.

When I have tried to install the package from 'NuGet' and 'All', I get
    Install-Package : Project 'Version=4.1.0.0' is not found.

However, I do have

```
 <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" 
 targetFramework="net40" />
```

in my packages.config file (though not in the bin folder). This later version that I have, doesn't seem to satisfy VS 2017. How can I resolve this error, please - it is preventing me from loading my aspx page in my browser.

Comment: Open a new empty project with new classes and aspx and copy just your code into it , it should work

Comment: Thank you, NaDeR Star - that's done the tick! I'm grateful!